How to make maven install checksum files to repo?
To generate checksums files I use this plugin:
    <plugin>
         <groupId>net.nicoulaj.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>checksum-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.9</version>
         <executions>
             <execution>
                 <goals>
                     <goal>artifacts</goal>
                 </goals>
             </execution>
         </executions>
     </plugin>

This plugin works as expected, when I do mvn install I see in target folder these files
foo-1.0.0.jar
foo-1.0.0.jar.md5
foo-1.0.0.jar.sha1
foo-1.0.0-javadoc.jar
foo-1.0.0-javadoc.jar.md5
foo-1.0.0-javadoc.jar.sha1
foo-1.0.0-sources.jar
foo-1.0.0-sources.jar.md5
foo-1.0.0-sources.jar.sha1

However, all my *.md5/sha1 files are not added to my local repo. Could anyone say how to fix it?
UPDATE - my pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>22</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>22</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>com.foo.foo.Foo</exec.mainClass>
        <javadoc.plugin.version>3.3.1</javadoc.plugin.version>
        <source.plugin.version>3.2.1</source.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javadoc.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <doclint>none</doclint>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${source.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.nicoulaj.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>checksum-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>artifacts</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


By default sha1/md5 etc. are generated by maven-install-plugin/maven-deploy-plugin why using supplemental checksum plugin? Please also share your full pom file...

@khmarbaise I posted my full pom. I couldn't make maven-install-plugin generate checksums. If you showed how to do it I would be very thankful.

Which version of maven-install-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin (all other plugins as well) are being used... furtgheremore why using jar goal of the javadoc ... why not jar-no-fork etc.. Which Maven verison do you use? which JDK? BTW: If using JDK9+ it's easier to use < maven.compiler.release>22</maven.compiler.release> instead of target/source...

@khmarbaise I use Apache Maven 3.9.6. It seems it uses  maven-install-plugin 3.1.1 by default. Thanks for pointing  jar-no-fork for javadoc. I missed that
